# Groovy script for scriptrunner

Tags: regex, groovy, bitbucket, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am currently working on a Scriptrunner script that has the objectives of rejecting push if the user pushes a not freeze dependancies. The script itself is not really hard but I don't know how to use Scriptrunner well enough to make it work, any advices ?

I tried several ways to make my script work, here is the script as it is right now :

```
def regex = ".*requires\\(\"[^\\d|_|\\-](\\S)+/\\[(\\d)(\\.\\d)*\\]@(eca|exail)/stable\""
def fileName = "conanfile.py"

def file = new File(fileName)

if (file.exists()) {
  file.readLines().each { line ->
    if (line.startsWith("self.requires")) {
      if (!(line =~ regex)) {
        log.error("Error: Freeze your dependancies")
        return false
      }
    }
  }
 // log.info("All 'self.requires' lines match the regex.")
  return true
} else {
  //log.error("Error: $fileName does not exist.")
  return true
}
```

as you can see it is pretty simple, we check if there is a file named "conanfile.py", and read it to find a line starting with "self.requires" and compare the line with our Regex ( the double \ is because of groovy). I am quite lost on how to make it works on Scriptrunner.

Answer (score 0):

to reject a push, you want to use a [Pre-Hook Script](https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4bib/latest/features/script-pre-receive-hooks) from ScriptRunner. In your script you will get several things injected, among others the repository and the ref changes.

To get the files, we first need to get the latest commit of the ref changes:

```
def commits = refChanges.getCommits(repository) as List<Commit>
def latestCommit = commits.first()
```

With that we can get the content of your file at that commit:

```
def fileStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
contentService.streamFile(repository, latestCommit.id, fileName) {
    fileStream
}
def content = fileStream.toString()
```

And that content you can then use like you did with the readLines and return a RepositoryHookResult. Putting everything together:

```
import com.atlassian.bitbucket.commit.Commit
import com.atlassian.bitbucket.content.ContentService
import com.atlassian.bitbucket.hook.repository.RepositoryHookResult
import com.atlassian.sal.api.component.ComponentLocator

def regex = '.*requires\("[^\d|_|\-](\S)+/\[(\d)(\.\d)*\]@(eca|exail)/stable"'
def fileName = "conanfile.py"

def contentService = ComponentLocator.getComponent(ContentService)

def commits = refChanges.getCommits(repository) as List<Commit>
def latestCommit = commits.first()

def fileStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
contentService.streamFile(repository, latestCommit.id, fileName) {
    fileStream
}
def content = fileStream.toString()

content.eachLine { line ->
    if (line.startsWith("self.requires")) {
      if (!(line =~ regex)) {
        return RepositoryHookResult.rejected('Push blocked', 'Error: Freeze your dependencies')
      }
    }
  }
  // log.info("All 'self.requires' lines match the regex.")
}

return RepositoryHookResult.accepted()
```

Be aware that this was written down without testing. So, some adjustment might be necessary.

I took this example script as example from Adaptavist: https://library.adaptavist.com/entity/block-commits-for-files-containing-content-that-doesnt-match-regex